# Silent mode is not work at viber app in desktop

Tags: c#, .net-core, viber-bot, viber-api

I use RichMediaButtons with silent mode true.
In phone, silent mode is ok but silent mode is not working on desktop. How to hide message in **viber** **chat**
.Please answer me.